# Remove an element from find return

Tags: javascript

With the fallowing  code I want to delete the last element inside the steps variable,

```
var steps = $(element).find("fieldset");
var count = steps.size();
steps[count-1] = null;
```

but when I iterate with the each method, it doesn't seems to see the null value

```
steps.each(function(i) {
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [*not()*](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to create a new jQuery object removing the elements you don't want:

```
steps = steps.not(steps.last());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function

```
steps = steps.slice(0, -1);
```